# Dell MD3000 - Resizing a virtual disk

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell, diskpart, dell-powervault

I've replaced some drives to our MD3000 with bigger ones.
These currently store database files used in a SQL Server 2005 cluster running on Windows Server 2003.

Now, we replaced the smaller hard drives with new bigger ones and let the array get rebuilt.
We now have enough free space.

We would like to extend this virtual disk to allow our databases to grow.

I've found this command by googling:

```
smcli -n MD3000 -c "set virtualdisk [\"Storage\"] addCapacity=400000000000";
```

My first question is, is this command safe to use while the databse server is running and hosts accessing this virtual disk?
Will it keep the data or will it wipe the data off the drive (of course, I'm going to have backups, but I would prefer not have to restore them for downtime reasons).

Then,it won't grow the actual partition for these drives.

I've seen that I can use the diskpart extend command.
Again, can it be used while the database server is running or does it need to be turned off?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, we usually make it in 3 moves (On HP Servers): First, Adding new Disks, Second, expand the volume in the Raid Tool (that didnt change the partition, only the volume). You will end with a Big disk with one partition and free space, the Third move is using gpart or any linux distro for Expanding the partition. The only point witch I'm not sure is the 2º one on Dell Servers. All 3 moves must be done with the SQL down to improve times.

Comment: I'm assuming the MD3000 is under a valid support contract with Dell. If so, and if it were me, I would call Dell and ask them. If this is your production system then it's nothing to trifle with or "guess" as to what might be the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the reconfiguration should be done in offline mode, i.e. the server using the storage should be down. Even if this is not the case (been a while since I've supported those boxes), I'd still stop the server and back it up before doing anything with the storage.

If you want a complete guide and step by step instructions, better give Dell support a call, it might be possible the entire reconfig is doable from MDSM, and there will be no need to go into the console.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the SMCli is a Windows application so it has to be run from the Server actively connected to the MD3000 I think and not from a console into the MD3000 itself.

Comment: MD3000 has an OOB management link, so it can be accessed via network from another machine running MDSM